# Ingest image to GCP Vertex AI Feature Store

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, feature-store

I want to ingest images to Vertex AI Feature Store from Cloud Storage.
In what format can I ingest images?

As documentation says:

For batch ingestion, Vertex AI Feature Store can ingest data from tables in BigQuery or files in Cloud Storage. For files in Cloud Storage, they must be in the Avro or CSV format.

For streaming ingestion, you provide the feature values to ingest as part of the API request. These source data requirements don't apply. For more information, see the writeFeatureValues API reference.

Answer (score 0):

Image data cannot be ingested into Vertex Feature Store. Only tabular data is supported.